# How to change empty spaces length between characters on UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to create spelling app but i stuck. User going to listen some word and will try to write it. i am trying to insert underline seperately to every characters on UITextField. Every underline will give a hint to user that how many characters exist in a word. Problem is some letters like "i","l" are so close to each other and i cant put same size underline to every letters. I could change empty blank length between characters on UITextField with this

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strText];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                         value:@(13)
                         range:NSMakeRange(0,[strText length] )];

txtTexts.attributedText = attributedString;
```

But it change for whole textfield with same length. I need different length for every letter. It looks fine with some words like this

[image]

But it is not fine with letters like "i" because they are closer to each other. [image]

Underlines are UIView by the way. But i m open to any advice.

Comment: You could use a monospaced font.

Comment: Thank you. It is very useful @Code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the new SF font. You can use monospaced font.

```
UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFontOfSize(, weight: )
```

Comment: Thank you very much. İ was in too deep and missed such a easy solution.